# What limitations does Webmin/Virtualmin have as opposed to cPanel/WHM?

Tags: webserver, webmin, virtualmin

I am using Virtualmin, and I would like to do everything possible in the beginning to make sure I can do all the same things as I could do with cPanel. It would create problems if down the road I discovered I could not do this or that on Virtualmin that I was accustomed to doing in cPanel.

I did find one thing so far. Apparently, Softacrulous, Simple Scripts, and Fantastico are not compatible with Virtualmin. Are there other significant limitations?

By the way, I am using CentOS 6, if that is relevant.

Answer (score 2):

This is an old question, but I thought I'd answer it anyway.

There are numerous differences between the two products in how features are presented, but they have near feature parity (there are actually many things Virtualmin+Webmin can do that cPanel cannot do, but they would rarely impact someone primarily managing websites, I'm not aware of anything cPanel/whm can do that Virtualmin+Webmin cannot do).

Virtualmin Professional includes a feature called "Install Scripts" which provides installation of 100+ web applications, similar to the tools you've mentioned. So, I don't think this can be considered a limitation of Virtualmin (though Virtualmin GPL only includes a very small number of Install Scripts, so if you're comparing free Virtualmin to paid-for cPanel plus paid for Fantastico, Virtualmin would not compare as favorably).

Here is a list of Install Scripts currently included in Virtualmin Professional: http://www.virtualmin.com/documentation/install-scripts

New scripts are added periodically, as users request them, and if they are reasonably easy and secure to deploy in a shared hosting environment.

I made a comparison table many years ago, which is kinda out of date at the moment, as it's missing much discussion of a lot of more modern features that have been added to Virtualmin and probably cPanel (stuff like node.js support, cloud service backup options, nginx support, etc.). But, I believe it is still accurate for the features it does cover.

http://www.virtualmin.com/compare.html

Disclaimer: I'm a developer on Virtualmin and work for Virtualmin, Inc.